# Another word for 'one-of-a-kind'

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for a specific adjective for a product (meaning something created by a human and not naturally occurring) where there is only one unit ever produced.

Similar meaning to *bespoke* but that implies it was created for a specific purpose. The word I'm thinking of can be used for items that don't serve a specific purpose; eg: *an art piece*.

By definition 'unique' fits, but in common usage it generally means *unusual*, and not specifically *one-of-a-kind*.

Sample sentence:

> Company XYZ acquires, restores and trades a variety of rarefied collectibles, from classic vehicles and timepieces to artworks and _______ artefacts.

**Example:** Handwoven carpets where they couldn't make another one exactly like it even if they tried. Or if Bugatti created a custom one-off car for a monarch.

**For clarity:** The word in question is not *one-of-a-kind, one-off, bespoke, unique* or *one-of-one*.

Note: This may be a loan word borrowed from another language, but generally accepted in English usage.

-EDIT-

With reference to comments below:

Agreed that this is not strictly a matter of language; rather, it is a matter of ***usage***. So yes, any answer ***would*** be a matter of opinion. However, I don't believe that equates to invalidating this query. *Unique* is academically correct, but considering this will be used in marketing material for the mass public, it's important to consider the commonly understood meaning and connotation. For instance, using 'one-of-a-kind' leaves less room for ambiguity than 'unique'.

Comment: You used it yourself-  *one-off*

Comment: 'Unique' _does_ mean 'the only one of its kind - the fact that some people use it to mean 'unusual' doesn't affect the correct definition.

Comment: academically correct, but considering this will be used in marketing material for the mass public, it's important to consider the commonly understood meaning and connotation. for instance, using 'one-of-a-kind' leaves less room for ambiguity than 'unique'

Comment: So, you are looking for a word meaning *one-off*, to be used in marketing a product. Has the item been produced yet? What's to stop anyone from making another one?

Comment: If this will be "used in marketing material" you are not looking for a "word" but a "buzzword". This is not a matter of *language*, then - at least in a strict sense, where "language" is a means to exchange *information*.

Comment: Unique is not synonymous with unusual.  It may be used reliably to describe something that is singular and not replicated elsewhere. Look at https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unique

Comment: The restriction of answers in the “for clarity”  section is a matter of opinion, not supported by any references. This means any answer will also be a matter of opinion, so the question should be closed.

Comment: Like "unique", "one-of-a-kind" doesn't require it's literally the only thing in existence - see [Cambridge Business English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/one-of-a-kind): "the only one of its type, or that is very unusual". You're tilting at windmills if you think you can find a completely unambiguous word in the English language that's never used in multiple contexts or with multiple meanings.

Comment: And nobody's going to believe an advertisement that says it's "one-of-a-kind" anyway; that's [the sort of claim advertisers make all the time](https://www.complex.com/style/2020/11/one-of-a-kind-jasmine-lasode) with minimal sincerity.

Comment: Seems that the English language, as is, isn't quite good enough for you. You need someone to  make up a bespoke, unique, one-of-a-kind sort of word. Tough!

Comment: "considering this will be used in marketing material for the mass public," I doubt that the general public would not understand the word *unique*. And artefacts cannot really be bespoke, unless they were created that way.  **unusual artefacts** might work, even if ripped off from some other country. {There's been a recent move to return artefacts to countries of origin.]

Answer (score 1):

Consider *sui generis*. It is another word for 'one-of-a-kind'. *OED* says that "Until the 19th cent. the term was primarily used in scientific writing.", but today, this term is used in various areas including creative arts. *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sui_generis)* has this information:

> A book, movie, television series, or other artistic creation is called *sui generis* when it does not fit into standard genre boundaries.

Here is a good explanation from *[vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/sui%20generis)*:

> Something *sui generis* is unique. If someone writes a sui generis book about whales wearing hats, then it’s the only one out there.
>
> The adjective *sui generis* is Latin, meaning literally, "of its own kind." Anything sui generis is its own thing; there’s nothing else like it. The Titanic was a sui generis ship because of its unmatched size and opulence as well as the preventable way it crashed into an iceberg and sank. Every person has a sui generis fingerprint, which is why thieves wear gloves.

**Important Note:** Please bear in mind that the usage of "unique artefacts" is much more common than "sui generis artefacts". Thus, I would suggest using the adjective *unique*. Here is a relevant usage from *[bbc.com](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-kent-60478577)*:

> Canterbury Cathedral: Unique artefacts go on display in new exhibition